# Access Modifier for Namespace

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can a function or sub-routine be accessed by the same namespace with the access modifier of private?

Or does the access modifier need to be public or internal?

Comment: Methods are contained in classes. They can only be accessed from the out-side if they are public. If you want to call it from a different namespace, you will simply need to add reference to the namespace that contains the class which the method belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a class you can access all methods and properties that belong to that class as well as any protected members exposed by its base class (if it has one).

Within another class in the same <strike>namespace</strike> assembly (or friend assembly) you can only reference the public or internal members of the first class.

Classes from other <strike>namespaces</strike> assemblies can only access public members.

Notes:

- namespaces are syntactic sugar provided by C#/VB, the real boundary for accessing internal methods is on assembly level. Namespaces by themselves have no visibility rules, nor change visibility of any entities.
- namespaces can span multiple assemblies and multiple namespaces can be in the same assembly.

Comment: I think the situation when using an '[extern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5(v=vs.80).aspx)' may be slightly different though? (Sorry meant for this to be a comment originally!)

Comment: +0. The answer is somewhat wrong (but ok for basic usage of namespaces) as it mixes assembly boundaries with syntactic sugar provided by namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my answer, Alexei.  You're absolutely right.

Answer (score -1):

Clearifying MSDN content about
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx